How can I make it so that when a value falls outside of a specific range a button starts flashing and when it returns it is the default color in QML
As the title says I am trying to write some code in qml that basically starts a warning flash whenever a value falls outside of what is set as "normal" and when it returns back within that range it returns back to the color specified.
I taught of giving the animation an id and doing the id.start whenever the if statement returns false but .start and .start() wouldn't work and kept resulting in errors. Right now the way I have it it starts out red and when it is supposed to turn green the animation starts (I have a loop running outside of this file to make the values climb from 0 to infinity).
Rectangle {
    x: -90
    width:  40
    height: 40
    color: (value1 <= 110) && (value2 >= 70) ? Qt.rgba(0,1,0,1) : Qt.rgba(1,0,0,1)
    radius: 35

    Behavior on color {
        SequentialAnimation {
            id: anim
            loops: Animation.Infinite
            ColorAnimation {from: "white"; to: "red"; duration: 300 }
            ColorAnimation { from: "red"; to: "white";  duration: 300        
        }
    }
}


you can base it on states, for example normal and alarmed and so switch from state to state on some condition, for example:
ColumnLayout {
    spacing: 10
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    Rectangle {
        id: lamp
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        width: 50
        height: 50
        radius: 25
        border.width: 5
        border.color: "#999"
        state:  "normal"
        states: [
            State {
                name: "normal";
                PropertyChanges { target: lamp; color: "#DEDEDE"; }
            },
            State {
                name: "alarmed";
            }
        ]
        transitions: [
            Transition {
                from: "normal"
                to: "alarmed"
                SequentialAnimation {
                    loops: Animation.Infinite
                    ColorAnimation { target: lamp; from: "yellow"; to: "red"; duration: 200 }
                    ColorAnimation { target: lamp; from: "red"; to: "yellow"; duration: 200 }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    
    Text {
        text: "accepted only: 3 >= x <= 7"
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    }
    
    SpinBox {
        id: valueBox
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        from: 0
        to: 10
        value: 5
        onValueChanged: {
            if(valueBox.value < 3 || valueBox.value > 7)
            {
                lamp.state = "alarmed";
            }
            else
            {
                lamp.state = "normal";
            }
        }
    }
}

or in some more declarative way:
State {
    name: "normal";
    PropertyChanges { target: lamp; color: "#DEDEDE"; }
    when: valueBox.value >= 3 && valueBox.value <= 7
},
State {
    name: "alarmed";
    when: valueBox.value < 3 || valueBox.value > 7
}

in this case SpinBox.onValueChanged should be removed of course

This answer is consistent with Qt's documentation. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-transition.html and https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-tutorial3.html

Well how what could I replace the spin box too? To add more context I need to have the animation trigger when values that are imported in from another file change. These variables would be changed outside of the gui so it would be like from a photoresist for example

of course, you can implement it in your own way. the code above is just for an example to illustrate the principle

You can split color into normalColor and errorColor so that, you can (1) switch between the two colors, (2) run the animation just on the errorColor:
Rectangle {
    property bool valid: (value1 <= 100) && (value2 >= 70)
    x: -90
    width:  40
    height: 40
    color: valid ? normalColor : errorColor
    property color normalColor: Qt.rgba(0,1,0,1)
    property color errorColor: Qt.rgba(1,0,0,1)
    radius: 35
    SequentialAnimation on errorColor {
        id: anim
        loops: Animation.Infinite
        running: !valid
        ColorAnimation {from: "white"; to: "red"; duration: 300 }
        ColorAnimation { from: "red"; to: "white";  duration: 300 }
    }
}

You can Try it Online!
